# Correct use of when() within a select()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to change the data in a column using `.when()`. I have tried doing this:

```
x = (
    spark.table('my_table')
    .select(
        'date'
        'id',
        .when(sf.col('name') == 'x', 'One'),
        .when(sf.col('name') == 'y', 'Two'),
        .when(sf.col('name') == 'z', 'Three'),
)
```

Though, my syntax seems to be wrong. I know in SQL I can achieve the same like so:

```
select
    date, id
    case
         when name = 'x' then 'One',
         when name = 'y' then 'Two',
         when name = 'z' then 'Three'
    end as name
from
    my_table
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first `when` should be `sf.when`, and the other `when`s should be attached to the first `when`:

```
x = (
    spark.table('my_table')
    .select(
        'date'
        'id',
        sf.when(sf.col('name') == 'x', 'One')
        .when(sf.col('name') == 'y', 'Two')
        .when(sf.col('name') == 'z', 'Three')
        .alias('name')
    )
)
```